# nested If in select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I combine these two queries?

```
select e.UserId, count(*) as [Registrations], min(uas.UserId), min(uas.[TimeStamp])
from Ev as e 
    left join UAS as uas on e.UserId = uas.UserId
where e.EventTypeId = 3 and e.Value is not null 
group by e.UserId 
having count(*) >= 10

if not exists (select * from Ev as e left join UAS as uas
                   on e.UserId = uas.UserId where uas.UserId = e.UserId)
begin
    insert UAS values (12, '2013-05-31 15:54:14.963')
end;
```

I want that if that UserId doesn't exist in UAS table insert it.

Comment: First query selects data and second inserts based on some condition. How should your potential "combined" query act? Should it really insert something or should it select some "dummy" values if there are no results in output of first query?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I know because asked. I want to insert when there's not such value already.

Comment: You can't combine insert and select queries in such a way. It should be separate queries anyway.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev there isn't any other solution?

Comment: Why do you want to combine these two queries? Whats the purpose, what are you trying to solve?

Comment: where does that date come from?

Comment: It's not possible to combine that SELECT query with that INSERT query, and it's very unclear what you think you would achieve if you could.   The first SELECT query doesn't have anything to do with the INSERT in the second query.   This is probably an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the below part using `WHERE NOT EXISTS`

```
if not exists (select * from Ev as e left join UAS as uas
                   on e.UserId = uas.UserId where uas.UserId = e.UserId)
begin
    insert UAS values (12, '2013-05-31 15:54:14.963')
end;
```

Like

```
insert into UAS 
select 12, '2013-05-31 15:54:14.963'
from Test // Test is a dummy dual table
where not exists (
select 1 from Ev as e 
left join UAS as uas
on e.UserId = uas.UserId where uas.UserId = e.UserId )
```

Comment: Hmm... how is it supposed to solve OP's task "combine some insert query with another select query"?

Comment: OP essentially checking if no record exists for the joined query then insert some data. That can be done using `insert .. select` construct. Right ???

Comment: As far as I've understood his question - he wants to combine this insert with the very first select query in the question (that one having group by). Maybe I'm wrong - but he didn't sheded any light on it in comments.

Comment: Isn't OP said *I want that if that UserId doesn't exist in UAS table insert it.* ??

Comment: Yes, it is about second query. But then what is the reason of existance the first one (with group by) query in the question? How is it related to the question at all in this case? Maybe you will be able to pull this secret from OP. ;)

Comment: No idea .. if the answer helps OP then cool else Go .. Went .. Gone